# Python - Transform a column witth the first 2 elements

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I've this code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None)
print((data[[7]].str[:2]))
```

My data is like this:

```
1,a,0,11,1,11.09,aa, 0 dollars
1,b,0,11,1,17.38,bb, 1 dollar
3,c,0,11,1,24.68,cdd, 12 dollares
```

And I'm trying to transform my dataset into:

```
1,a,0,11,1,11.09,aa, 0
1,b,0,11,1,17.38,bb, 1
3,c,0,11,1,24.68,cdd, 12
```

When I run my code I'm getting this error:

```
builtins.AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

How can I transform my data into the data I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need remove one `[]` for `Series`, here double `[]` create one column `DataFrame`:

```
data[7] = data[7].str[:2]
print (data)
   0  1  2   3  4      5    6   7
0  1  a  0  11  1  11.09   aa   0
1  1  b  0  11  1  17.38   bb   1
2  3  c  0  11  1  24.68  cdd   1
```

But if want extract numeric value use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)and cast to `integer`s:

```
data[7] = data[7].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)
print (data)
   0  1  2   3  4      5    6   7
0  1  a  0  11  1  11.09   aa   0
1  1  b  0  11  1  17.38   bb   1
2  3  c  0  11  1  24.68  cdd  12
```

Comment: many thanks!!!! To transform the column into my dataset I just need to use Apply function?